# 301 redirect specific file in subfolder to same file in root?

Tags: .htaccess, file, redirect

I've searched stackoverflow, but can't seem to find an exact answer.

I would like to 301 redirect all files that match a filename in all subdirectories to the same file name in the root directory of the same domain.

eg:

/any-sub-directory/specific-file.html to http://example.com/specific-file.html

Hope that makes sense?  :/

Many thanks

Mr M

Comment: Try [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.+/specific-file\.html$ /specific-file.html
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

If you prefer to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+/specific-file\.html$ /specific-file.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, the 1st worked a treat. the 2nd killed the site for osme reason. Just before I picked up your answer, i also tried:    RewriteRule (.*)/specific-file.html /specific-file.html [R=301,L]   Which seems to work, but I suspect it may be open to abuse?

Comment: @DMurray sorry, that `Cond` should have been a `Rule`

Comment: Ah, thanks again, that works now too. Which is the best method? I'm just cutting down on unnecessary content and want to keep Google happy.

Comment: @DMurray they work the same, just different modules. Google won't be able to tell the difference. It's a matter of how you've got your site setup. If you use a lot of mod_rewrite, then sometimes it's better to stick with that rather than mixing your redirects between the two different modules.

Comment: I use mod_rewrite all the time, so will stick with that for the 301's too, as per your suggestion. Thanks again Jon  :)

Comment: @DMurray just make sure the rules that redirect are *before* the ones that internally rewrite